# Programming with MAF (and MEF) on Mono

Tags: mono, mef, maf

I am currently working as an internship in a company who wants to make software for the linux platform. Since they are a .Net minded company, they want me to look into mono.
I kinda have to look if it is stable for their applications and server apps.

I am now studying the MEF and MAF ( Managed AddIn Framework ) frameworks in mono.

Does anyone have some experience in building applications with the MEF and MAF framework in MONO? Did you experience some problems on mono etc? (and solutions are welcome (: )

I tested some easy tutorial code of MEF and that worked fine with mono (although I didn't use all functions they give me).
About MAF I didn't find that much that could help me. Any links that could help me?
To be more specific, I wonder if there exists some posts about MONO & MAF if it works or not.

I already thank you for reading my question,

Benjamin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF works on Mono, once you apply 2 patches so that it works on case-sensitive file systems.  Mono 2.8 will ship with MEF in the next few weeks: http://mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8.

I use MEF for Pinta on .Net and Mono: http://github.com/jpobst/Pinta.  My usage is trivial, but it works great.

I do not know anything about MAF.

Comment: Could you tell me witch 2 patches? I seen IOmap, but i dont think that you meaned...

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure MAF is not and will not be available on Mono.

The source code to MEF was released with a license that allowed it to be incorporated into Mono.  The source code to MAF has not been released at all as far as I know, and I don't think there is any interest in rewriting it for Mono.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of MAF in Mono is [Mono.Addins](http://www.mono-project.com/Introduction_to_Mono.Addins). I think it's not quite the same API as MAF, but it provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

An open source implementation of MAF can be found here [System.AddIn](https://bitbucket.org/hindlemail/system.addin.dll) Its not 100% feature complete but can be used on Linux, with mono, running addins in separate processes.